# Is it possible to terraform a hot planet?

Tags: planets, climate, terraforming

I want to make a hot planet habitable for mankind. It could be a planet in the habitable zone like Venus or outside of the zone like Mercury. These are just examples.

Someone said here: [Terraforming a very cold planet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2479/terraforming-a-very-cold-planet) that terraforming a cold planet is easier that a hot one. Still, is it possible to make a planet colder?

> Example 1:  A planet in the habitable zone is too hot for human
>   habitation due to atmospheric reasons. Can it be cooled down?
>
> Example 2:  A planet is too hot due to solar proximity.  Can it be cooled
>   down? Can it be moved away from the star?

What are the different techniques or technologies that could be used to lower the surface temperature of a planet?

*including possible not too far future technologies.

Comment: Can you specify why the planet is hot?  Lack of atmosphere, too much atmosphere, volcanic, solar proximity?  This will help focus the question a bit.

Comment: Yea, all of these factors except for the volcanic activity. I think this could be for another question maybe. Is it too broad ?

Comment: I suggested and edit of what I had in mind if you want to take a look.

Comment: Some of [these proposals](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/earth/environment/climatechange/8169039/Cancun-climate-change-summit-UN-considers-putting-mirrors-in-space.html) for fighting global warming on earth might (in a larger scale) also be applicable to hot planets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally you have two choices (assuming we don't have some sort of super future tech like planetary force fields, portals, moving the planet into a larger orbit, cooling the sun, etc).

- Increase outgoing heat
- Reduce incoming heat

The first one could be tried a little using giant heat sinks or similar but is not really practical so that leaves the second option of reducing incoming heat.

Now you have three choices:

- Make the planet's surface more reflective

For example ice caps reflect away a lot of incoming heat. Similar could be done with artificial substances.

- Make the planet's atmosphere retain less heat/more reflective

Dust in the upper atmosphere similar to an Impact/Volcanic/Nuclear winter could reflect away heat. Stripping out greenhouse gasses would cause it to retain less heat.

- Block the heat before it reaches the planet

A giant mirror, sail or similar placed in space between the sun and the planet could reduce the incoming sunlight.

Comment: I don't think you'd want a single giant mirror.  Use a swarm of thousands/millions of small ones.  They'd only need to be a few atoms thick, so wouldn't require that much total mass (maybe a smallish asteroid), and could to some extent be maneuvered as solar sails.

Comment: @jamesqf Not a bad idea, you'd tend to lose the small mirrors over time and need to keep replacing them though. They'd also be harder to keep in position.

Comment: Do they need to be mirrors? Aren't they simply casting a shadow on the planet? If the "shaders" themselves warm up, what does it matter? That heat won't be transferred to the planet.

Comment: @wetcircuit true enough. Mirrors will radiate less and might let you harness the energy somehow. Just shades is simpler though.